# Ray-plane intersection to find the Z of the intersecting point

Tags: 3d, mouse, coordinates, intersection

I have a rectangle in 3d space `(p1, p2, p3, p4)` and when the mouse rolls over it I need to calculate the exact Z of the point on the rect, given the mouse coordinates `(x, y)`.

Would a Ray-plane intersection find the Z of the intersecting point?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try a ray / plane intersection. Check: [Object/Object intersection](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html).

Comment: Oh yes, or so I just found out. But I'm writing this in raw C#, so any I'm looking for some code that's simple to port... can you help?

Comment: Would this ray-to-plane intersection code work? http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=270743